# Word Choice- Prepositions

Tags: prepositions

How can I phrase correctly "from where his PhD is". In the context of presenting someone, "He is XX, PhD from XX University"? or "XX, Phd of XX University"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're presenting the person in a social context, describe his/her credentials in full sentences. "This is XYZ, she has a PhD in oceanic science from the University of Neverland", or "XYZ obtained a PhD from Neverland University. She's an expert in green turtles." If it's on a formal piece of writing, "XYZ, PhD (U. of Neverland)" suffices.